# How to create a Polygon with holes GEOS library

Tags: c++, geos

I'm using the GEOS library, and I'm trying to create a `Polygon` with a hole in it. As per the [documentation](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1GeometryFactory.html#a9057fce375090cdb60e0cc5d2828e248), I have to pass in a `LinearRing`, which represents the outer "shell", and a `std::vector<Geometry*>`, which represents the holes in the shell. The first parameter is easy, but the second one is giving me trouble. `Polygon` wants the elements in the second parameter to be `LineString`s (`LineString` is a subclass of `Geometry`); otherwise, it throws an exception saying that `LineString`s are needed for the holes. If I just cast the `LineString`s to `Geometry`, then it throws the exception. If I don't cast it, I get a compile error saying that pointers of one type can't be cast into pointers of another type. I can't figure out what to do here.

Here's a short code sample that demonstrates the error:

```
geos::geom::CoordinateSequence* temp = factory->getCoordinateSequenceFactory()->create((std::size_t) 0, 0);

temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(0, 0));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(100, 0));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(100, 100));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(0, 100));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(0, 0));

geos::geom::LinearRing *shell=factory->createLinearRing(temp);

temp = factory->getCoordinateSequenceFactory()->create((std::size_t) 0, 0);

temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(1, 1));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(10, 1));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(10, 10));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(1, 10));
temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(1, 1));

geos::geom::LinearRing *hole=factory->createLinearRing(temp);
holes->push_back((geos::geom::Geometry*) hole);

factory->createPolygon(shell,holes);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

I had an include line that included `geos/geom/GeometryFactory.h`. In that file, there was a forward-declaration to `geos::geom::LinearRing`, but it didn't say that that class was a subclass of `geos::geom::Geometry`. Therefore, the compiler treated it as two different classes. Having `#include <geos/geom/LinearRing.h>` fixed it.